# Find area and perimeter of shape formed by graph of $|y| = \cos(x)$

Tags: calculus

[image]

My working:

> Area:
>
> - $\cos(x) = 0$
> - $x = \cos^{-1}(0) = ±\frac{\pi}{2}$
> - Area = $2\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos(x) dx$
> - Area = $2((\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}) - (\sin(-\frac{\pi}{2}))) = 2(1 + 1) = 4$
>
> Perimeter:
>
> - Perimeter = $2\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sqrt{1 + (\frac{d}{dx}(\cos(x)))^2} dx$
> - Perimeter = $2\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sqrt{\sin^{2}(x) + 1} dx$
> - let $u = \sin^2(x) = (\sin(x))^2$
> - $x = \sin^{-1}(\sqrt{u})$
> - $du = 2\sin(x)\cos(x)dx$
> - $dx = \frac{du}{2\sin(x)\cos(x)}$
> - $\int \frac{\sqrt{u^2 + 1}}{2\sin(\sin^{-1}(\sqrt{u}))\cos(\sin^{-1}(\sqrt{u}))} du$
> - $\frac{1}{2} \int \sqrt{\frac{u^2 + 1}{u - u^2}} du$

I couldn't solve this integral - I went to check WolframAlpha and it doesn't have an elementary antiderivative so I must have gone wrong somewhere - but I can't see where.

Comment: I made an amazing edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. Except using special functions ([elliptic integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral)), you cannot compute
$$\text{Perimeter}=\int_{-\frac \pi 2}^{+\frac \pi 2}\sqrt{\sin ^2(x)+1}\,dx=2\int_{0}^{\frac \pi 2}\sqrt{\sin ^2(x)+1}\,dx$$ using elementary functions.

If you want to *approximate* it, write for example
$$\int_{0}^{\frac \pi 2}\sqrt{\sin ^2(x)+1}\,dx=\int_{0}^{\frac \pi 4}\sqrt{\sin ^2(x)+1}\,dx+\int_{\frac \pi 4}^{\frac \pi 2}\sqrt{\sin ^2(x)+1}\,dx$$ and use two series expansions
$$1+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{7 x^4}{24}+\frac{121 x^6}{720}-\frac{5167
   x^8}{40320}+O\left(x^{10}\right)$$
$$\sqrt{2}-\frac{\left(x-\frac{\pi }{2}\right)^2}{2 \sqrt{2}}+\frac{5
   \left(x-\frac{\pi }{2}\right)^4}{48 \sqrt{2}}+\frac{11 \left(x-\frac{\pi
   }{2}\right)^6}{2880 \sqrt{2}}-\frac{11 \left(x-\frac{\pi }{2}\right)^8}{64512
   \sqrt{2}}+O\left(\left(x-\frac{\pi }{2}\right)^{10}\right)$$ and integrate termwise.

I let you this part of the work.

Numerically, it will give for the perimeter $3.81923$ while the exact value is $3.82020$.

**Edit**

You can do better and simpler if you perform the expansion of the integrand around $x=\frac \pi 4$.

$$\sqrt{\sin ^2(x)+1}=\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}+\frac 1{\sqrt 6}\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \left(x-\frac{\pi }{4}\right)^n$$ where the first coefficients are
$$\left\{1,-\frac{1}{6},-\frac{11}{18},\frac{43}{216},\frac{107}{3240},-\frac{403}{6480}
   ,\frac{2287}{45360},-\frac{65773}{3265920},\cdots\right\}$$ This would give
$$\int_{0}^{\frac \pi 2}\sqrt{\sin ^2(x)+1}\,dx=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}} \pi+\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{6}}\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{2n} \frac{ \pi ^{2 n+1}}{(2 n+1)\, 2^{4 n}}$$ We shall not need to add many terms for a good approximation
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & \text{approximation}\\
 1 & 1.90185 \\
 2 & 1.91156 \\
 3 & 1.91023 \\
 4 & 1.91002 \\
 5 & 1.91009 \\
 6 & 1.91011 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$ to be compared to the exact $1.91010$